# Rails display html tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to display html tags via Rails.
I'm using Rails 2.3
I've tried  these ways

```
<p class="value"><%= raw @agent_event_monitor.name %></p>
<p class="value"><%= @agent_event_monitor.name.html_safe %></p>
<p class="value"><pre><code><%= @agent_event_monitor.name.html_safe %></code></pre></p>
```

but none doesn't give any result
on @agent_event_monitor.name is something like this

```
<b><p>Hello</p></b>
```

Comment: try helper `h` `<p class="value"><%= h(@agent_event_monitor.name) %></p>`

Comment: Are you sure `@agent_event_monitor.name` is not `nil`?

Comment: @fivedigit `nil` would throw an exception.

Comment: Yes it's can't be nil

Comment: Thanks for help.
All rights now.

Comment: have you solved the problem? if yes how?

Answer (score -1):

If you want HTML tags displayed, not rendered, in the browser, you need to ***escape*** them when printing them to your HTML document. Both `raw` and `.html_safe` do the opposite -- they ***unescape*** your HTML tags, ensuring that they ***are*** rendered in the browser.

To ensure your HTML tags are escaped, you need to use the `h` helper. The code would look like this:

```
<p class="value"><%= h @agent_event_monitor.name %></p>
```